# In netty4 is there an guaranteed order between notifications after connecting to remote server?

Tags: netty

When one calls `channel.connect` a future is returned. Then for each outbound-handler `.connect()` is called passing a promise. (I guess they are really the same object, but let's ignore that.) So far so clear.

At some point listeners added to (a) the future, to (b) the promise are notified about completion. Also, at some point (c) `.channelActive()` will be called on all inbound handlers (as far as I understood this replaces .connected from netty-3.x). And finally there is the point in time (d) when `isActive()` returns true for the first time.

**Question:** Is there a defined order between (a) to (d)?

**Context:** I'm trying to implement a handler that writes a message to the channel on connection. It works mostly well, but sometimes it seems that handler is not the first one to get to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is guaranteed but it may trigger an event earlier then you are able to add the listener itself as everything is async. If you want to make sure that your ChannelFutureListener is called before channelActive() in all cases you can just create a ChannelPromise via channel.newPromise() add a ChannelListener to it and then pass the ChannelPromise to the connect method.

The contract is that the ChannelPromise will always be notified before the corresponding methods in ChannelOutboundHandler/ChannelInboundHandler

Comment: So the promise that is passed in the outboundhandler.connect is notified before channelActive handlers are called. Right? Moreover, is there a guaranteed order between listeners on the same promise/future? I.e., if I want to be sure that some handlers listener is notified before any listeners up the stack, I have to create a new promise (for the ctx.connect call) and notify the one the handler received as argument afterwards.